# Ncryptoki error no 208 / 209 (importing certificates)

Tags: c#, pkcs#11

I have problems importing a certificate into Alladin eToken with NCryptoki.

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(test.cer);
byte[] id = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("MyKeyPairID");
CryptokiCollection template = new CryptokiCollection();
template.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_CLASS, CryptokiObject.CKO_CERTIFICATE));
template.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_CERTIFICATE_TYPE, Certificate.CKC_X_509));
template.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_TOKEN, true));
template.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_PRIVATE, false));
template.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_LABEL, "MyLabel"));
template.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_ID, id));
template.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_SUBJECT, cert.SubjectName.RawData));
template.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_ISSUER, cert.Issuer));
template.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_SERIAL_NUMBER, cert.GetRawCertData()));
template.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_VALUE, cert.RawData));
CryptokiObject certificate = session.Objects.Create(template);
```

I get error 209 (0xD1) `CKR_TEMPLATE_INCONSISTENT`. If I delete this line:

```
template.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_VALUE, cert.RawData));
```

I get error 208 (0xD0) `CKR_TEMPLATE_INCOMPLETE`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are setting wrong values for `CKA_SUBJECT`, `CKA_ISSUER` and `CKA_SERIAL_NUMBER` attributes.

Following code with [Pkcs11Interop](https://www.pkcs11interop.net) and [BouncyCastle](http://bouncycastle.org/csharp/index.html) libraries is usually working for me:

```
/// <summary>
/// Imports certificate into the PKCS#11 compatible device
/// </summary>
/// <param name="session">Session with user logged in</param>
/// <param name="certificate">Certificate that should be imported</param>
/// <param name="ckaLabel">Value of CKA_LABEL attribute</param>
/// <param name="ckaId">Value of CKA_ID attribute</param>
/// <returns>Handle of created certificate object</returns>
public static ObjectHandle ImportCertificate(Session session, byte[] certificate, string ckaLabel, byte[] ckaId)
{
    // Parse certificate
    X509CertificateParser x509CertificateParser = new X509CertificateParser();
    X509Certificate x509Certificate = x509CertificateParser.ReadCertificate(certificate);

    // Define attributes of new certificate object
    List<ObjectAttribute> certificateAttributes = new List<ObjectAttribute>();
    certificateAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_CLASS, CKO.CKO_CERTIFICATE));
    certificateAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_TOKEN, true));
    certificateAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_PRIVATE, false));
    certificateAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_MODIFIABLE, true));
    certificateAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_LABEL, ckaLabel));
    certificateAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_CERTIFICATE_TYPE, CKC.CKC_X_509));
    certificateAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_TRUSTED, false));
    certificateAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_SUBJECT, x509Certificate.SubjectDN.GetDerEncoded()));
    certificateAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_ID, ckaId));
    certificateAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_ISSUER, x509Certificate.IssuerDN.GetDerEncoded()));
    certificateAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_SERIAL_NUMBER, new DerInteger(x509Certificate.SerialNumber).GetDerEncoded()));
    certificateAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_VALUE, x509Certificate.GetEncoded()));

    // Create certificate object
    return session.CreateObject(certificateAttributes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the serial number with the certificate raw data:

```
template.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_SERIAL_NUMBER, cert.GetRawCertData()));
```

You set it in the following way:

```
template.Add(new ObjectAttribute(ObjectAttribute.CKA_SERIAL_NUMBER, cert.SubjectDN.GetDerEncoded()
```